# how to add properly the value of counter to a variable name

Tags: javascript, variables

it can seems easy, but I'm little lost...
What I need is to add the counter value to a variable name.

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
   var upBt0; //this is the name in the first iteration
   var upBt1; //this is the name in the second iteration
   .
   .
   .
   var upBt8; //this is the name in the last iteration
}
```

How can I do this properly?
Sorry, Daniel

**EDIT:**

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        this.upBt = "upBt"+i;
        this.upBt = new PL_Button().init("upBarButton"+i);
}
```

I create buttons...in particular 8 buttons...
And later, I need access to each of these buttons:

```
function (){
    this.upBt1;
    this.upBt1;
    this.upBt3;
    this.upBt6;
}
```

Hope have explained better.

**EDIT 2**: 
Finally, I solved it using an auxiliar array of the class, where I pushed each object in each iteration. Each item of this array is a real reference to each object, so changed the item in the array, changes are also made in the corresponding object...
Hope have explained well.

Thanks for your help,
Daniel

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It seems like an array or object is what you need.

Comment: Hi elclanrs, because I need access to these variables later...really I'll create variables with this.upBt1, this.upBt2.... there're variables of a class and I need access to them values later...thanks

Comment: Seems like this is not right approach though, can you post some more code? This looks like an XY problem...

Comment: I agree with elclanrs. From what it seems is all you need is an array of objects of the class that you have and then you can initialize/pass/use the objects as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, but it's ugly code...

```
for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
   this["upBt" + i] = Object.create(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array helped to me:

```
this._arrayButtons = {};
for (var i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    this.upBt = new PL_Button().init("upBarButton"+i);
    this.upBt.imgPath = "res/builder/"+upBarImgs[i];
        .
        .
        .
    this._arrayButtons[i] = this.upBt;
}
```

After, in one function, I can access to the content of the variables such as:

```
function refreshFrameAlpha(){
    this._arrayButtons[3].alpha = 125;
    this._arrayButtons[5].alpha = 225;
    .
    .
}
```

In this way, I can refresh alpha (p.e) of the object, because each item of the array is a reference to the corresponding object.